# How to connect to database in real server

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, connection

I am trying to connect to my database wich it created in **PhpMyAdmin** in my own server.
I write the code in a php file as below:

```
<?php 
   echo "welcome";
   echo "<br>";

   $conn = mysqli_connect("mydomainename.com:2080", "database_user_in phpmyadmin", "password of my database name", "name of database");
   $result = mysqli_query( $this->conn, "SELECT * FROM `ad` WHERE 1"); 
   while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array( $result ) ) {
      $ad_level = $row['ad_level']; 
   }
   echo $ad_level;
?>
```

If I access to this page , its just return : **welcome** 
I think that the error in the syntax of 'mysqli_connect' ....  ist correct ??
have anyone any idea about this ?????

How do I do that? I googled a lot, but either I used the wrong keywords or there are no simple solutions on the internet. I hope somebody here can help me.

Best regards and thanks in advance, Fadel.

Comment: Please define __Real server__

Comment: what you meen in real server ??? I have a real server with my specific domaine name

Comment: may be this can help you http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php

Comment: congratulation on having a real server but i am curious to know difference between a _server_ and _a real server_ ?

Comment: Dear ... Im new in this !! its the first time when i connect to my database :( ... can you help me please cause i think you touch my fault and my conflict :(

Comment: can you [get in here(php chat room)](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11/php) ?

Comment: @Fadel do a thing which works out best in my case.
call the hosting server people. they can get u through it.
it always works best in my case.

Comment: Sorry @dhpratik what you meen in 'call the hosting server people' ... you meen that to tag the hosting server in my question??

Comment: @Fadel 'call the hosting server people'

Comment: @dhpratik ... nope :( i didn't get the solution :(

Comment: mmmmm .... i replaced 'mydomainename.com:2080' by 'localhost' and now it worck !!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("mydomainename.com:2080", "database_user_in phpmyadmin", "password of my database name", "name of database");
```

by this:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "database_user_in phpmyadmin", "password of my database name", "name of database");
```

but why !!! i have not any idea !! just it worck ... why ???? have anyone any idea about this ????

Comment: i guess ur domain is on bigrock, cause in big rock they used to give me db host name as `localhost`

Comment: @BinaryMan maybe because you used wrong syntax? :)
`$link = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "my_user", "my_password", "my_db", "port");`

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php

Answer (score 4):

the real syntax is

`mysqli_connect(host,username,password,dbname,port,socket);`

so as you have written host name along with the port there must be an error.
you can refer the below link for more insite

http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_connect.asp

Answer (score 1):

Try this

Use `$conn` in place of `$this->conn`

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `ad` WHERE 1");
```

If you have `error` in `mysqli connection` the use `die` after this `function` like

```
$conn= mysqli_connect("myhost","myuser","mypassw","mybd") 
                     or die("Error " . mysqli_error($conn));// use die here
```

Read this http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php

Comment: I think that for OP it would be more valuable to write **why** it is probably the case, not just give a code solution

Comment: I think my conflict in this line:
mysqli_connect("mydomainename.com:2080", "database_user_in phpmyadmin", "password of my database name","name of database");
what you think about it ??

Comment: I don't know your `db credentials` if the **problem** is `mysqli_connect` then `die` after `mysqli_connect`. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the general mySQL DB Connection Process:

```
<?php
   // Create connection
   $con = mysqli_connect("example.com", "peter", "abc123", "my_db");

   // Check connection
   if ( mysqli_connect_errno( $con ) ) {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
   }
?>
```

Comment: i try it ... it returned :
Failed to connect to MySQL: Host '50-87-5-24.unifiedlayer.com' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server

Comment: Try mysql instead of mysqli_

Comment: Please check my another another i just posted. Its in working condition with me

Answer (score -1):

Try this way. I am currently using this method and its working perfect:

```
<?php

    $server = "localhost";
    $login = "root";
    $pw = "myPassword";
    $db = "myDatabase";


$con = mysql_connect($server, $login, $pw);

mysql_select_db($db, $con);

$qry = "select * from members where Username ='$Username' and Password = '$Password' and Status = 1" ;

    $conQry = mysql_query($qry , $con);



?>
```

**NOW YOU CAN FETCH YOUR DATA**

Comment: this is `mysql_connect` and he is asking `mysqli_connect`. you see there is a difference.

Comment: @Necromancer. ... i try it .. I have this error :
Host '50-87-5-24.unifiedlayer.com' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server

Comment: You should check your host settings. there might be some problem with your host